# How to mock XCM origin in tests?

Tags: xcm, mock

My custom pallet has a couple of XCM calls, for which I have to provide the `Origin` in `mock.rs`. It implements the

```
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        ...

        type Origin: From<<Self as SystemConfig>::Origin>
            + Into<Result<CumulusOrigin, <Self as Config>::Origin>>;

        type XcmSender: SendXcm;
    }
```

I have tests for the "ordinary, non-XCM" functions and with now adding the XCM, this does not compile (due to requiring `CumulusOrigin`). I do not care for testing XCM calls, so a dummy `Origin` would work well, however I am not sure how to implement it. I do not find any examples with such mocking (XCM pallets on github do not have tests). How can I do this?

---

**Stuff I tried.**

I tried to mock everything:

```
use frame_support::{
    parameter_types,
    traits::{ConstU64, Everything},
    weights::{IdentityFee, Weight},
};
use frame_system as system;

use sp_core::{
    offchain::{testing, OffchainWorkerExt, TransactionPoolExt},
    sr25519::Signature,
    H256,
};

use sp_runtime::{
    testing::{Header, TestXt},
    traits::{BlakeTwo256, Extrinsic as ExtrinsicT, IdentifyAccount, IdentityLookup, Verify},
};
use xcm::latest::{prelude::*, Junction, OriginKind, SendXcm, Xcm};
use xcm_builder::{
    AllowUnpaidExecutionFrom, EnsureXcmOrigin, FixedWeightBounds, LocationInverter,
    SignedToAccountId32,
};
use xcm_executor::{
    traits::{InvertLocation, TransactAsset, WeightTrader},
    Assets, XcmExecutor,
};

type UncheckedExtrinsic = frame_system::mocking::MockUncheckedExtrinsic<Test>;
type Block = frame_system::mocking::MockBlock<Test>;

// Configure a mock runtime to test the pallet.
frame_support::construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Test where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        System: frame_system::{Pallet, Call, Config, Storage, Event<T>},
        Balances: pallet_balances::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Config<T>, Event<T>},
        XcmPallet: pallet_xcm::{Pallet, Call, Event<T>, Origin, Config} = 31,
        CumulusXcm: cumulus_pallet_xcm::{Pallet, Event<T>, Origin} = 32,
        MyPallet: my_pallet::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>},
    }
);

parameter_types! {
    pub const BlockHashCount: u64 = 250;
    pub const SS58Prefix: u8 = 42;

    pub static AdvertisedXcmVersion: xcm::prelude::XcmVersion = 2;
    pub const UnitWeightCost: Weight = 10;
    pub const MaxInstructions: u32 = 100;
    pub const RelayNetwork: NetworkId = NetworkId::Any;

    pub Ancestry: MultiLocation = Parachain(2001).into();
}

impl system::Config for Test {
    type BaseCallFilter = Everything;
    type BlockWeights = ();
    type BlockLength = ();
    type DbWeight = ();
    type Origin = Origin;
    type Call = Call;
    type Index = u64;
    type BlockNumber = u64;
    type Hash = H256;
    type Hashing = BlakeTwo256;
    type AccountId = u64;
    type Lookup = IdentityLookup<Self::AccountId>;
    type Header = Header;
    type Event = Event;
    type BlockHashCount = BlockHashCount;
    type Version = ();
    type PalletInfo = PalletInfo;
    type AccountData = pallet_balances::AccountData<u64>;
    type OnNewAccount = ();
    type OnKilledAccount = ();
    type SystemWeightInfo = ();
    type SS58Prefix = SS58Prefix;
    type OnSetCode = ();
    type MaxConsumers = frame_support::traits::ConstU32<16>;
}

impl pallet_balances::Config for Test {
    type Balance = u64;
    type DustRemoval = ();
    type Event = Event;
    type ExistentialDeposit = ConstU64<1>;
    type AccountStore = System;
    type WeightInfo = ();
    type MaxLocks = ();
    type MaxReserves = ();
    type ReserveIdentifier = [u8; 8];
}

pub struct DummyWeightTrader;
impl WeightTrader for DummyWeightTrader {
    fn new() -> Self {
        DummyWeightTrader
    }

    fn buy_weight(&mut self, _weight: Weight, _payment: Assets) -> Result<Assets, XcmError> {
        Ok(Assets::default())
    }
}
pub struct DummyAssetTransactor;
impl TransactAsset for DummyAssetTransactor {
    fn deposit_asset(_what: &MultiAsset, _who: &MultiLocation) -> XcmResult {
        Ok(())
    }

    fn withdraw_asset(_what: &MultiAsset, _who: &MultiLocation) -> Result<Assets, XcmError> {
        let asset: MultiAsset = (Parent, 100_000).into();
        Ok(asset.into())
    }
}
pub struct XcmConfig;
pub struct DoNothingRouter;
type AccountId = <<Signature as Verify>::Signer as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;

pub type LocalOriginToLocation = SignedToAccountId32<Origin, AccountId, RelayNetwork>;
pub type Barrier = AllowUnpaidExecutionFrom<Everything>;

impl SendXcm for DoNothingRouter {
    fn send_xcm(_dest: impl Into<MultiLocation>, _msg: Xcm<()>) -> SendResult {
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl xcm_executor::Config for XcmConfig {
    type Call = Call;
    type XcmSender = DoNothingRouter;
    type AssetTransactor = DummyAssetTransactor;
    type OriginConverter = pallet_xcm::XcmPassthrough<Origin>;
    type IsReserve = ();
    type IsTeleporter = ();
    type LocationInverter = LocationInverter<Ancestry>;
    type Barrier = Barrier;
    type Weigher = FixedWeightBounds<UnitWeightCost, Call, MaxInstructions>;
    type Trader = DummyWeightTrader;
    type ResponseHandler = ();
    type AssetTrap = XcmPallet;
    type AssetClaims = XcmPallet;
    type SubscriptionService = XcmPallet;
}

impl pallet_xcm::Config for Test {
    type Event = Event;
    type SendXcmOrigin = EnsureXcmOrigin<Origin, LocalOriginToLocation>;
    type XcmRouter = DoNothingRouter;
    type LocationInverter = LocationInverter<Ancestry>;
    type ExecuteXcmOrigin = EnsureXcmOrigin<Origin, LocalOriginToLocation>;
    type XcmExecuteFilter = Everything;
    type XcmExecutor = XcmExecutor<XcmConfig>;
    type XcmTeleportFilter = Everything;
    type Weigher = FixedWeightBounds<UnitWeightCost, Call, MaxInstructions>;
    type XcmReserveTransferFilter = Everything;
    type Origin = Origin;
    type Call = Call;
    const VERSION_DISCOVERY_QUEUE_SIZE: u32 = 100;
    type AdvertisedXcmVersion = AdvertisedXcmVersion;
}

impl cumulus_pallet_xcm::Config for Test {
    type Event = Event;
    type XcmExecutor = XcmExecutor<XcmConfig>;
}
```

but I get:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<OriginCaller as TryInto<RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>>>::Error == OriginCaller`
   --> my_pallet/src/mock.rs:154:26
    |
154 |     type SendXcmOrigin = EnsureXcmOrigin<Origin, LocalOriginToLocation>;
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `OriginCaller`, found enum `std::convert::Infallible`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `xcm_executor::traits::Convert<mock::Origin, xcm::v1::MultiLocation>` for `SignedToAccountId32<mock::Origin, sp_core::sr25519::Public, RelayNetwork>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `EnsureOrigin<mock::Origin>` for `EnsureXcmOrigin<mock::Origin, SignedToAccountId32<mock::Origin, sp_core::sr25519::Public, RelayNetwork>>`
note: required by a bound in `pallet_xcm::Config::SendXcmOrigin`
   --> /home/user/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-4038f27d5e4ea2e8/b017bad/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs:78:65
    |
78  |         type SendXcmOrigin: EnsureOrigin<<Self as SysConfig>::Origin, Success = MultiLocation>;
    |                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `pallet_xcm::Config::SendXcmOrigin`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `OriginCaller: From<RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>>` is not satisfied
   --> my_pallet/src/mock.rs:154:26
    |
154 |     type SendXcmOrigin = EnsureXcmOrigin<Origin, LocalOriginToLocation>;
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>>` is not implemented for `OriginCaller`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <OriginCaller as From<RawOrigin<u64>>>
              <OriginCaller as From<cumulus_pallet_xcm::Origin>>
              <OriginCaller as From<pallet_xcm::Origin>>
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `xcm_executor::traits::Convert<mock::Origin, xcm::v1::MultiLocation>` for `SignedToAccountId32<mock::Origin, sp_core::sr25519::Public, RelayNetwork>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `EnsureOrigin<mock::Origin>` for `EnsureXcmOrigin<mock::Origin, SignedToAccountId32<mock::Origin, sp_core::sr25519::Public, RelayNetwork>>`
note: required by a bound in `pallet_xcm::Config::SendXcmOrigin`
   --> /home/user/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-4038f27d5e4ea2e8/b017bad/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs:78:65
    |
78  |         type SendXcmOrigin: EnsureOrigin<<Self as SysConfig>::Origin, Success = MultiLocation>;
    |                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `pallet_xcm::Config::SendXcmOrigin`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>: From<OriginCaller>` is not satisfied
   --> my_pallet/src/mock.rs:154:26
    |
154 |     type SendXcmOrigin = EnsureXcmOrigin<Origin, LocalOriginToLocation>;
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<OriginCaller>` is not implemented for `RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>`
    |
    = help: the trait `From<std::option::Option<AccountId>>` is implemented for `RawOrigin<AccountId>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>>` for `OriginCaller`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `TryFrom<OriginCaller>` for `RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `TryInto<RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>>` for `OriginCaller`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `xcm_executor::traits::Convert<mock::Origin, xcm::v1::MultiLocation>` for `SignedToAccountId32<mock::Origin, sp_core::sr25519::Public, RelayNetwork>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `EnsureOrigin<mock::Origin>` for `EnsureXcmOrigin<mock::Origin, SignedToAccountId32<mock::Origin, sp_core::sr25519::Public, RelayNetwork>>`
note: required by a bound in `pallet_xcm::Config::SendXcmOrigin`
   --> /home/user/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-4038f27d5e4ea2e8/b017bad/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs:78:65
    |
78  |         type SendXcmOrigin: EnsureOrigin<<Self as SysConfig>::Origin, Success = MultiLocation>;
    |                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `pallet_xcm::Config::SendXcmOrigin`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<OriginCaller as TryInto<RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>>>::Error == OriginCaller`
   --> my_pallet/src/mock.rs:157:29
    |
157 |     type ExecuteXcmOrigin = EnsureXcmOrigin<Origin, LocalOriginToLocation>;
    |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `OriginCaller`, found enum `std::convert::Infallible`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `xcm_executor::traits::Convert<mock::Origin, xcm::v1::MultiLocation>` for `SignedToAccountId32<mock::Origin, sp_core::sr25519::Public, RelayNetwork>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `EnsureOrigin<mock::Origin>` for `EnsureXcmOrigin<mock::Origin, SignedToAccountId32<mock::Origin, sp_core::sr25519::Public, RelayNetwork>>`
note: required by a bound in `pallet_xcm::Config::ExecuteXcmOrigin`
   --> /home/user/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-4038f27d5e4ea2e8/b017bad/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs:86:68
    |
86  |         type ExecuteXcmOrigin: EnsureOrigin<<Self as SysConfig>::Origin, Success = MultiLocation>;
    |                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `pallet_xcm::Config::ExecuteXcmOrigin`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `OriginCaller: From<RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>>` is not satisfied
   --> my_pallet/src/mock.rs:157:29
    |
157 |     type ExecuteXcmOrigin = EnsureXcmOrigin<Origin, LocalOriginToLocation>;
    |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>>` is not implemented for `OriginCaller`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <OriginCaller as From<RawOrigin<u64>>>
              <OriginCaller as From<cumulus_pallet_xcm::Origin>>
              <OriginCaller as From<pallet_xcm::Origin>>
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `xcm_executor::traits::Convert<mock::Origin, xcm::v1::MultiLocation>` for `SignedToAccountId32<mock::Origin, sp_core::sr25519::Public, RelayNetwork>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `EnsureOrigin<mock::Origin>` for `EnsureXcmOrigin<mock::Origin, SignedToAccountId32<mock::Origin, sp_core::sr25519::Public, RelayNetwork>>`
note: required by a bound in `pallet_xcm::Config::ExecuteXcmOrigin`
   --> /home/user/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-4038f27d5e4ea2e8/b017bad/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs:86:68
    |
86  |         type ExecuteXcmOrigin: EnsureOrigin<<Self as SysConfig>::Origin, Success = MultiLocation>;
    |                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `pallet_xcm::Config::ExecuteXcmOrigin`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>: From<OriginCaller>` is not satisfied
   --> my_pallet/src/mock.rs:157:29
    |
157 |     type ExecuteXcmOrigin = EnsureXcmOrigin<Origin, LocalOriginToLocation>;
    |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<OriginCaller>` is not implemented for `RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>`
    |
    = help: the trait `From<std::option::Option<AccountId>>` is implemented for `RawOrigin<AccountId>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>>` for `OriginCaller`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `TryFrom<OriginCaller>` for `RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `TryInto<RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>>` for `OriginCaller`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `xcm_executor::traits::Convert<mock::Origin, xcm::v1::MultiLocation>` for `SignedToAccountId32<mock::Origin, sp_core::sr25519::Public, RelayNetwork>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `EnsureOrigin<mock::Origin>` for `EnsureXcmOrigin<mock::Origin, SignedToAccountId32<mock::Origin, sp_core::sr25519::Public, RelayNetwork>>`
note: required by a bound in `pallet_xcm::Config::ExecuteXcmOrigin`
```

At this point I've tried so many things, I am thinking of removing tests rather than making it work. I would rather not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the [xcm-examples repository](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-docs/tree/main/examples) and use the [setup up](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-docs/blob/main/examples/src/simple_test_net/mod.rs) it has for testing, mocking the runtime and some of the features you need to mock for  testing XCM calls.